# Creating a nested dictionary (using a for loop?)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a beginner in python and currently a little confused about something. I have a list of 7 variables called "variables" and I also have a large tsv file called "file". In column 1 of the tsv file, there are multiple entries of the 7 variables in the "variable" list, and for each entry of the variables, there are results in column 2, looking like this but on a larger scale (without the header):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| variable1 | result1 |
| variable1 | result2 |
| variable1 | result3 |
| variable1 | result4 |
| variable1 | result5 |
| variable2 | result6 |
| variable2 | result7 |
| variable2 | result8 |
| variable2 | result9 |
| variable3 | result10 |
| variable4 | result11 |
| variable4 | result12 |
| variable4 | result13 |
| variable5 | result14 |
| variable5 | result15 |
| variable5 | result16 |
| variable6 | result17 |
| variable7 | result18 |
| variable7 | result19 |
| variable7 | result20 |

etc etc

I want to create a nested dictionary called "results" in which each dictionary within "results" is corresponding to each of the 7 variables, the keys are the results specific to the variable, and the values for each key are all "1" (I will write over the values at a later stage).

Like this:

```
results =  {'variable1': {'result1': '1', 'result2': '1','result3': '1', 'result4': '1', 'result5': '1'},
'variable2': {'result6': '1', 'result7': '1' etc...},
'variable3': {'result10': '1'},
'variable4': {'result11': '1', 'result12': '1' etc...},
'variable5': {'result14': '1', 'result15': '1' etc...},
'variable6': {'result17': '1'},
'variable7': {'result18': '1', 'result11': '1' etc...}}
```

I really don't know how to proceed with this. I know the answer is probably really simple but I'm a beginner and have zero idea how to move forward. I hope you can help :)

Comment: Since your `variableX` keys are numbered, wouldn’t make it more sense to use a list instead of a dictionary for the outer part?

Answer (score 1):

The term "nested" dictionary you are using is a bit misleading.
Essentially you just want to accumulate results by variables.

You can take the following approach,

```py
with open("path-to-file", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    rows = [line.split('\t') for line in content.split('\n')]

results = {}

for row in rows:
    varname, result = row[0], row[1]
    if results.get(varname) is None:
        results[varname] = {result: "1"}
    else:
        results[varname][result] = "1"
```

`results.get()` is a way of checking if the value exists in the dictionary or not. If it does not, `None` is returned, triggering the first part of the condition to initiate the dictionary, else just adding to it.

You can of course optimize things, use other in-built structures if those suit your needs better. For example, in case you were interested in counts of variable-result pairings, you could do something like

```py
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

# read rows as above

results = defaultdict(Counter)

for row in rows:
    results[row[0]].update([row[1]])
    # results[row[0]][row[1]] += 1  # another way
```

This avoids the checks, and will produce a dictionary with number of times a result appears with `variableX`

Comment: I upvoted but note OP wanted  string`"1"` rather than number `1` (i.e. just a small change to your solution).

Comment: Actually, your soltuion produces a key error.

Comment: I updated it, the if condition was actually revered. (Also fixed `"1"`, although that bit OP is anyway going to overwrite later it would seem, so the value doesn't really matter)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following code produces your desired results

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    results = {}              # dictionary to hold results
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()  # remove '\n' at end of line
        v, r = line.split()   # get variable and result
        results.setdefault(v, {})  # adding a dictionary for variable var (if it doesn't exists)
        results[v][r] = "1"   # Adding key with results and number
    
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(results)                   # Using pretty-print rather than normal print to show structure
```

**Output**

```
{'variable1': {'result1': '1',
               'result2': '1',
               'result3': '1',
               'result4': '1',
               'result5': '1'},
 'variable2': {'result6': '1', 'result7': '1', 'result8': '1', 'result9': '1'},
 'variable3': {'result10': '1'},
 'variable4': {'result11': '1', 'result12': '1', 'result13': '1'},
 'variable5': {'result14': '1', 'result15': '1', 'result16': '1'},
 'variable6': {'result17': '1'},
 'variable7': {'result18': '1', 'result19': '1', 'result20': '1'}}
```